# Cant search for custom CBUUID

Tags: swift, xcode, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have an app that works (so far so good) in connecting my iOS device to a bluetooth arduino, as of now this has been mostly for practice, but now I received the real thing that I'm supposed to connect to.
The problem is that I can't find it! (when I search for it).
If I do scanwithservices: nil, I can see the device and connect to it. However if i scanwithservices: [device'sCBUUID] then I don't get anything.
I double/triple/quatrupled checked the CBUUID using other apps, using my own app and looking at the device documentation, however no matter what I can't find it.
It has a custom CBUUID, from what I've read that's not standard, the CBUUID is:

```
BLETPodService = CBUUID(string: "4D494B45-414c-5741-5953-524F434B5321")
```

Searching for this yields nothing, however if I scan for nil I find it and if i check it's characteristics using the Bluefruit app (from Adafruit) I can see it's services and characteristics ID and they match that string I posted in here!
I told a friend and he said it's a BLE bug thats been there for ages (regarding custom CBUUIDs), is this true? is there really no fix for this?

*EDIT* adding the full scanning code just FYI:

```
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        var statusMessage = ""

        switch (central.state)
        {
        case .unsupported:
            statusMessage = "Bluetooth Low Energy is not supported!"
            displayStatusAlert(localmsg: statusMessage)
            print(statusMessage)
        case .unauthorized:
            statusMessage = "Bluetooth Low Energy is not authorized!"
            displayStatusAlert(localmsg: statusMessage)
            print(statusMessage)
        case .unknown:
            statusMessage = "Bluetooth Low Energy is unknown!"
            displayStatusAlert(localmsg: statusMessage)
            print(statusMessage)
        case .poweredOff:
            statusMessage = "Bluetooth Low Energy is powered off!"
            displayStatusAlert(localmsg: statusMessage)
            print(statusMessage)
        case .resetting:
            statusMessage = "Bluetooth Low Energy is resetting!"
            displayStatusAlert(localmsg: statusMessage)
            print(statusMessage)
        case .poweredOn:
            statusMessage = "BLE is ready!" //If BLE is ready then start scanning right away!
            peripheralsFoundNames.removeAll()
            peripheralsFoundCB.removeAll()
            peripheralsFoundRSSIs.removeAll()
            peripheralsFoundData.removeAll() //Remove previous data from previous scans
            central.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)
        }
    }

//What happens when you discover a peripheral
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        //What to do when it discovers a peripheral, add it to the array list
        print("Peripheral found: " + (peripheral.name ?? "Unknown Name"))
        peripheralsFoundNames.append((peripheral.name ?? "Unknown Name"))
        peripheralsFoundData.append((advertisementData.description ))
        peripheralsFoundCB.append(peripheral)
        peripheralsFoundRSSIs.append(RSSI)
    }
```

Comment: That's not true.You can scan for specific custom UUIDs. You might want to have "repeating Scan Responses" from an object, maybe yours only appeared once? Try the code below: 

let bleQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "BLEQueue",attributes: [],target: nil)

let options = [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: true]
let cbManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: bleQueue)

let serviceUUIDs = [CBUUID(string: "4D494B45-414c-5741-5953-524F434B5321")]
cbManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: serviceUUIDs, options: options)

Comment: Additionally, please provide more code to get a better understanding of how your Core Bluetooth layer is supposed to being set up.

Comment: First thing: if you scan with nil services, and you print advertisement data of the didFindPeripheral method, does your services appears? If not, you won't find it, because `scanWithServices:[someService]` will work only if it advertised. If it appears on it the advertisement data, could you show the log. I'm not sure if the CBUUID on iOS is case sensitive (there is an lower "c" on yours, while the other letters are upper case).

Comment: Added more code as requested. Thing is the code already works with another bluetooth module (nRF8001), however this is a custom device that our EE is developing and it has its own custom CBUUID. I thought I could just replace the CBUUID I was scanning for and that would be the end of it but it seems that doesn't work. Scanning nil discovers the device, however searching for it specifically does not

Comment: Lepidopteron, can you elaborate on that code you suggested? where do I implement that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had this problem, but I've found some tricky way.

You can try to match UUIDs (string value) directly in didDiscoverPeripheral func:

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber){
  if let services = peripheral.services {
        for service in services {
            if service.uuid.uuidString.lowercased() == "4D494B45-414c-5741-5953-524F434B5321".lowercased() {
              if !peripheralsFoundCB.contains(peripheral) {
                   peripheralsFoundCB.append(peripheral)
              }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If this way doesn't work for you I have one more:

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber){
    peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
}

func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
     if let services = peripheral.services {
        for service in services {
            if service.uuid.uuidString.lowercased() == "4D494B45-414c-5741-5953-524F434B5321".lowercased() {
              if !peripheralsFoundCB.contains(peripheral) {
                   peripheralsFoundCB.append(periphera
              }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course you should use

> scanwithservices: nil

Comment: Thank you, I think that first suggestion will work. Although this just shows that there is a bug with the software? or hardware? so you can't scan directly for the devices? you have to filter them out afterwards?

Comment: I don't think that this is a bug. I think that something should be set on the peripheral side. I don't have practice on hardware side so I can't answer you exactly.

Answer (score 5):

I happen to be working on both BLE firmware and iOS App at the same time.
I had the same issue that the filter not working.

The reason that iOS couldn't find the device with the UUID is that the device doesn't include the UUID when it is advertising.

I had to change the device firmware to add service UUID in the advertising data packet. With device advertising the UUID, UUID filter worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3:

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {

    self.selectPeripheral.discoverServices(nil)
}

func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {

   let services = peripheral.services as [CBService]!{

        for service in services{

            if service.uuid.uuidString == "4D494B45-414c-5741-5953-524F434B5321"{
               print("service found")
            }
        }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am having exactly the same issue. Currently I might do the same solution suggested by the folks here! But I think its a problem from the hardware side.

I believe what is happening that your EE is not broadcasting the service UUID! What I mean by that if you printed the advertisedInfo you will not see the the following key-value pair in the info:

```
"kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs": <__NSArrayM 0x14e6f3b0>("Your CBUUID")
```

You might see the name key-value and other stuff but definitely not the one I specified.

For that reason if he can do his part by broadcasting the service UUID's then you will be able to scan for that using the following method.

```
scanForPeripherals(withServices: ["Your CBUUID"], options: nil)
```

And you will see it :)